# Unable to fetch file path from uri in Android M

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow, android-snackbar, snackbar, android-6.0.1-marshmallow

I am able to get the files path from URI fetched from notification bar but I could only fetch it from URI received from Android Snackbar.

Current function used to fetch the path:

Note: This works fine for pre-Marshmallow Android versions.

```java
private String extractContentUri(Uri uri) {

  Cursor cursor = null;

  try {

    cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, null, null, null, null);
    Log.d("CHECK", "COUNT" + cursor.getCount());

    if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
      Log.d("CHECK", "CURSOR !NULL");
      launchedFile = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("_data"));
      Log.d("CHECK", "==" + launchedFile);
      return launchedFile;
    }
  } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {

  } finally {
    Log.d("CHECK", "{finally} ==" + launchedFile);
    if (cursor != null) {
      cursor.close();
      cursor = null;
    }

  }
  return null;
}
```

In android M the URI obtained while accessing the from notification bar and from snackbar are different.

- URI from notification bar: `content://downloads/all_downloads/1449`
- URI from snackbar: `content://downloads/my_downloads/1449`

```java
cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, null, null, null, null);
```

here the cursor`.getCount()` is always 0 for snackbar.

Comment: @Alqueraf: code snippet added

Answer (score 0):

You need to add Runtime permission for Android 6 and above version. Please check [this](http://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html) for Run time permission.

Comment: if that's the case then it shouldn't work from the notification bar also, right?

Comment: ya if that is this case

Comment: But am able to handle it from notification bar.
 Also
In android M the uri obtained while accessing the from notification bar and from snackbar are different. 
uri from notification bar: content://downloads/all_downloads/1449 
uri from snackbar: content://downloads/my_downloads/1449

cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, null, null, null, null); here the cursor.getCount() is always 0 for snackbar.